# How to add back button in maps app for windows store apps (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs, windows

In my maps app i want add a back button in my  which goes back in the navigation stack. I tried creating a button element and adding to map using map.entities.push and adding a click event to it, but it dint work. Should i add a map overlay or something. What am i doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know how to add a button in a map, I'm not sure it's even possible. I added an AppBar to the page where the map shows and that's where I added my buttons. Hope it helps. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229670.aspx

Comment: Could you share a snippet. Ive tried it and it dosent work. var appBar = document.createElement('div');
        var command = document.createElement('button');

        new WinJS.UI.AppBar(appBar);
        new WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand(command, { label: 'Hello', icon: 'add' });

        appBar.appendChild(command);

        document.body.appendChild(appBar);

Comment: try with the html provided in the help page... that should work.